# Accessing 'data/internal_memory' on Android phone

Tags: c#, android, file-io, xamarin.android, xamarin

Hi I bought a cheap Android phone to do app debugging on, and I would like to know how to access the internal memory folder, which is rejecting my advances.

When I first got the phone I downloaded some pictures from the internet using the browser. I also took a photo with the camera. They were stored in internal memory because I had not installed a SD card.

Then I installed an SD card, and downloaded some more images with the browser, which were stored on the SD card. Now when I look in the gallery there are different folders for the images on the SD card and the ones in internal memory.

I am writing a C# application using Xamarin to browse the pictures, but when I try to reach /data/internal_memory, I receive a permissions error. I can however access the folder using a file manager app (Easy Files Finder). I assume that this is because Easy Files Finder made me accept various permission exceptions before installation.

What do I have to do in my application to give me read access to the internal storage? Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 0):

As Google says:

"You can save files directly on the device's internal storage. By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user). When the user uninstalls your application, these files are removed."

But you can try this:

1. Call openFileInput() and pass it the name of the file to read. This returns a FileInputStream.
2. Read bytes from the file with read().
3. Then close the stream with close().

See [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. In my case, a) my app is not the one that created the files, the browser did; b) the saved files are public, ie they are visible in Gallery, and are not private to the browser, so presumably I can get to them; c) I dont know what the names of the saved files are, I need to browse the folder to find them, so passing the name of the file is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Accessing internal memory may be restricted. I'd try searching here:

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
```

To access files on the SD card use `Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath`.